# Length of array in React isn't matching up to the number of elements it has

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Everytime my card component is clicked it is running the `cardSelected()` function. I can see that the state array ***selected*** is being correctly updated with the card ids but when I check the length of the array after using `setState()` it is one out.

1. array starts empty
2. after first card is clicked, the array is updated with with the card id
3. `console.log(this.state.selected.length)` straight after still shows the length as `0` when I am expecting it to be `1` and can see it has `1` value in state.

```js
cardSelected = id => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    selected: [...prevState.selected, id]
  }));

  console.log(this.state.selected.length);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `setState` is async.

In order to work, fix it as follows with a callback, executed after the state is updated:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  selected: [...prevState.selected, id]
}),
() => console.log(this.state.selected.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because setState may be asynchronous, I recommend the reading of this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

On your code, you can use a callback function as a second argument to the setState function, that will be executed when the new state is defined.

```
cardSelected = id => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    selected: [...prevState.selected, id]
  }), () => {
    console.log(this.state.selected.length)
  });
};
```

Comment: The official documentation explicitly describes that 'state updates may be asynchronous'

Answer (score 0):

As some of the peers answered, setState is asnyc. Not that there's anything wrong with code people suggested. I think you can write your logic better in the below way.

```
cardSelected = id => {
        const selected = [...this.state.selected, id];
        this.setState({ selected: selected });
    };
```

And you can better debug your state values using [react developer tools chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) instead of logging everything. If you still feel like logging to console is better, then you can try logging in **render()** method or **componentDidUpdate()** as they are the right places to check your data.